# TYPO3 Header Date wrong year?

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-7.6.x

I am using the typoscript:

```
lib.stdheader.5.strftime = %G
```

to have the header date show only the year. However when the date is set to 01/01/2006 the output is 2005. Is this a bug? It only seems to happen on January 1st.

Also, is there a way to limit the date picker to only use years? (not day or month)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

%G is unknown for me. Maybe it should be %Y to output the year? Which "data" does lib.stdheader.5 for strftime?

Comment: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/DataTypes/Strftimeconf/Index.html

Comment: Ah I didn't read the description fully, %G uses ISO-8601:1988 standards. %Y is what I should be using. Do you know if it is possible to customize the date picker to only pick year?

Comment: Which datepicker do you mean? The one of the backend?

Comment: Yeah the backend one. I thought I would be good to change it to a year picker so it's not confusing for the client to update.

Comment: Didn't find anything about telling the TCA to only show a year-datepicker. But instead of using a date field you can just use a integer field in the tca with a range configured like upper = 1990 and upper 2050 so an editor has to enter a valid year.

Comment: I'm not making an extension, just modifying the normal text/images element with typoscript. But thanks for you help!